# How to proceed with HybridAuth 3 without endpoint method

Tags: authentication

I´ve decided to migrate HybridAuth 2 to version 3 and i got really confused about how it should work.

I was using the "endpoint logic" from version 2:

1. The user clicks on button "login with whatever" to be redirected to login method
2. At the login Method...Construct the HybridAuth object and calls authenticate method, surrounded by try/catch methods.
3. The user is redirected outside to login page on the provider site to do whatever it needs to.
4. If okay, the user is sended back to the endpoint page, different from the login page. On this page, i construct the HybridAuth object and calls the process_endpoint method.

But there is no endpoint method anymore on HybridAuth 3!

I´ve followed the tutorials on official Hybrid site, but when i go log in with Google+, im beeing redirect to the outside provider twice! And its obvious! This is what that method should do in first place! But at the step 4, i had no reference from the early authenticate process, because everything goes OK at step 2 and the user was redirected to outside my page.

So, what should i do on endpoint process with HybridAuth 3??? How should i avoid the provider login screen to be called twice?